# How to simulate "server down" situation using Burp suite proxy?

Tags: http-proxy, burp

I tried using Burp suite to simulate the above for a particular domain. I am a beginner on this and don't know how to set it up. I couldn't find a built-in option for this.

Also, if there is no option, will I need to forward the request to some random IP address so that the connection gets timed out?

### Update

Actually I doubt if redirecting to some invalid IP will give a connection timeout. Or will it give a timeout? I just want to know what response will I get if the server is down.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a feature to simulate "server down" but you can redirect as you suggest. If you redirect to an unused IP address (perhaps 192.168.99.99) you will normally get a timeout.

You can configure this in Proxy > Options > Proxy Listeners > Edit > Request Handling

Answer (score -1):

You can just edit the response code to be a [server error](https://www.lifewire.com/500-internal-server-error-explained-2622938). You can do this automatically using [match and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684024/burp-extension-add-header-to-response/37736825#37736825) as well.