# burp extension how to intercept all traffic

Tags: python, jython, burp

I am currently developing a burp extension using python/jython.

My desired outcome is to be able to interact with every part of burp (more specifically the intruder) and replace a header on every single request burp makes, regardless of what part of burp makes the request.

let us for arguments sake say the request header that I wish to modify is "Accept-Language" and I wish to change its value from de to en.

How would I do this with emphasis being on the "every single request" or if that is too much, interacting with only the "intruder" requests would be a great start.

Note: I do not want to create an intruder payload, I need to change headers based upon the request.

Comment: show us the code you have written so far.

Comment: @neuhaus there is no code to show I am asking for a basic template. What ever code or links I am given i will work with and build around the examples. I am currently learning, this is my next step.

Comment: you may not need an extension, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684024/burp-extension-add-header-to-response

Comment: @neuhaus my plugin this is for  custom hashing, need to generate the hash based on the contents of the request. thanks for the link anyhow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using the [IHttpListener](https://portswigger.net/Burp/extender/api/burp/IHttpListener.html) interface. When the listener is registered, the *processHttpMessage* method is called for every request and response. Inside this method you can use *analyseRequest* to extract the headers. Make the changes you need, then use *buildHttpMessage* and *setRequest*.

Here is some code to try.

```
from burp import IBurpExtender, IHttpListener

class BurpExtender(IBurpExtender, IHttpListener):
    def registerExtenderCallbacks(self, callbacks):
        self.helpers = callbacks.getHelpers()
        callbacks.registerHttpListener(self)

    def processHttpMessage(self, toolFlag, messageIsRequest, message):
        if not messageIsRequest:
            return
        request = message.getRequest()
        requestInfo = self.helpers.analyzeRequest(request)
        headers = requestInfo.getHeaders()
        for i in range(len(headers)):
            if headers[i].startswith('Accept-Language: de'):
                headers[i] = 'Accept-Language: en'
        body = request[requestInfo.getBodyOffset():]
        updatedRequest = self.helpers.buildHttpMessage(headers, body)
        message.setRequest(updatedRequest)
```

You may also be interested in our [sample extensions](https://portswigger.net/burp/extender). Also, all the BApp Store extensions are open-source.